# Your experience with LibSourcey

Tags: c++11, websocket, webrtc, libuv, libsourcey

Just came across [libsourcey](http://sourcey.com/libsourcey/) when Googling libuv. It looks very featureful, but I haven't been able to find any solid reviews or benchmarks (in fact, this seems to be the first post here on stack overflow concerning LibSourcey.)

Has anybody yet to have any experience with this framework?

Comment: I'm downloading now and will spend the next couple days playing with this. This is likely to become pretty popular if it isn't overly hyped.

Comment: I poked around a bit but it seemed over complicated and bloated for my needs.

Comment: @JSON Hey JSON, what was your experience with libsourcey ?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your interest in LibSourcey! As the maintainer I can say the library is still under active development. There are a number of startups that currently use it in their proprietary code - and maybe some open source code too - so it will continue to be developed and will *always* remain open source.

Since it was open sourced in '14 it hasn't gained a huge amount of open source adoption, probably since it was never advertised there are already some great alternatives such as `boost`, but hopefully the power of modern `stl` and `libuv` will attract more developers over time.

I'll personally be happy to answer any questions regarding LibSourcey.

Comment: may be you can help with realtime?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071796/libsourcey-realtime-video-translation