# LibSourcey realtime video translation

Tags: c++, webrtc, libsourcey

I found LibSourcey library for webrtc video translation. I added stream from web cam to LibSourcey, instead test.mp4 file from file system. But in the browser I see one or two second delay between real situation and video into browser.

Can I reduce the delay time? I need create realtime video stream from device. Any idea?

Comment: We need to see code to be able to help you.

Comment: LibSourcey only handles the actual signaling part of the webrtc communication, so the video related aspect is most likely due the webrtc buffering the frames. Is the stream only delayed when using webcam capture, or is it the same when reading from file? How are you initiating the capture?